# How to access or retrieve SSRS table ExecutionLog3 in CRM

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2008-r2

I am looking for report's parameter which is stored in the table ExecutionLog3 on ReportServer database.

Is it possible to access that table through any batchjob or javascript from CRM itself (not using SQL)?

Can anyone give idea, if it is possible at all.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Execution logs are native to the SQL Report Server and not CRM. It's an entirely different database.  Unless you have a custom object to do exactly this (access report serve logs) then there is no way to do this. So, no.. there is no built in functionality for this.

Comment: Hello Harry,
I got your point and same we are facing. Can you please ellaborate about custom object's idea if you have any ?
I am able to access report server and it's rdl by methods exposed by the service endpoint of report server but bot able to access instances of those reports.
Is there any idea you have which can be achieved by either SP or something like this.

Comment: If you can access the rdl why not write a report targeting the execution logs using the report server database as a target and then access it the same way?